# jq: use variable to identify an inner object key to append to

Tags: json, bash, key, jq

I've been researching this for a bit and I've seen answers that have gotten me closer to solving this, but nothing that actually gets me all the way there.

I have the following JSON file:

```
{
  "applications": {
    "app1": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "filename": "install_latest_app.pkg",
        "version": "1.2.3",
        "date": "20190903"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "filename": "install_latest_app.pkg",
        "version": "1.2.4",
        "date": "20190904"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "filename": "install_latest_app.pkg",
        "version": "1.2.5",
        "date": "20190905"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to use jq in a Bash script to dynamically add entries to this file under the specific "app". In my example there's only one "app" defined (app1) but in a real world scenario there would be more.

```
#!/bin/bash

title="app1"
filename="install_latest_app.pkg"
version="1.2.6"
date="20190906"
id="6"

jq --arg title "$title" \
--arg filename "$filename" \
--arg version "$version" \
--arg date "$date" \
--arg id "$id" \
'.applications.$title += [{"id": $id, "filename": $filename, "version": $version, "date": $date}]' data.json >> data.json
```

when trying to run this, I get a compile error.

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.applications.$title += [{"id": $id, "filename": $filename, "version": $version, "date": $date}]
```

Same when running it in ways like `.applications.[$title]` or `(.applications.[$title])` (all based on other discussions).

If I do something like `.applications | .[$title] |= ...` I get a lot closer as it actually returns the JSON with the correct entries, however it doesn't add it to the current "app1", instead adding a new entry for "app1". I would be fine overwriting the entire file every time with the added entry, but I am struggling to get it to print the entire JSON + the new entry. Any help or ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: `jq --arg title "$title" --arg filename "$filename" --arg version "$version" --arg date "$date" --arg id "$id" '.applications[$title] += [{"id": $id, "filename": $filename, "version": $version, "date": $date}]'` works fine, so the claim that you get the "same when running it ways like[...]" needs to be demonstrated.

Comment: ...or, rather: You were close with `applications.[$title]`, but had an extra `.` that isn't valid syntax; make it `.applications[$title]` and you're good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `.applications.$title` or `.applications.[$title]`, use `.applications[$title]`, as in:

```
jq --arg title "$title" \
   --arg filename "$filename" \
   --arg version "$version" \
   --arg date "$date" \
   --arg id "$id" '
  .applications[$title] += [{$id, $filename, $version, $date}]'
```

...and output is correctly:

```
{
  "applications": {
    "app1": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "filename": "install_latest_app.pkg",
        "version": "1.2.3",
        "date": "20190903"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "filename": "install_latest_app.pkg",
        "version": "1.2.4",
        "date": "20190904"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "filename": "install_latest_app.pkg",
        "version": "1.2.5",
        "date": "20190905"
      },
      {
        "id": "6",
        "filename": "install_latest_app.pkg",
        "version": "1.2.6",
        "date": "20190906"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably not coincidental that this is similar to how you do it in JavaScript.

Comment: ...or Python, or Ruby, or most other recent languages that using square brackets for interacting with maps.

Comment: My point was that it's like JS's `object.literalProp` vs `object[variableProp]`. Python doesn't have that distinction. He was making the same mistake that many JS beginners do by trying to write `object.variable`